# Unable to install Xcode 5 under Yosemite

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-yosemite

I've installed Yosemite (developer preview) on my mac. After that, I'm not able to install Xcode from App Store. Error message:

"Xcode can not be installed because your OSX version is too new."

Is there any way to avoid that ?

Comment: You'll probably have to boot up using Mavericks or else you're stuck with Xcode 6 Beta

Comment: Finally I've managed to extract a XCode 5.1 from my TimeMachine backup. Obviously there is no way to get it from Apple. Thanks @Mikael!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download any version of Xcode 5 from the Apple Developer Downloads [website](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action#downloads) and install it from .dmg

[image: Apple developer portal - downloads]

Comment: Would work, so for anyone having trouble installing XCode 5 on Yosemite - that's the solution!